# Is SMTP safe to use in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
username = input("Type your e-mail and press enter: ")
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', port=587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login(username, password)
s.set_debuglevel(1)

msg = MIMEText("""body""")

sender = 'my_mail@hotmail.com'
recipients = ['recipient@hotmail.com']
msg['Subject'] = "Hello"

msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

And I'm just wondering, how safe is it to write your password in this script? Is there anything that I should be worried about in terms of getting a password leaked? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have `starttls()`, so that's better than plaintext

Comment: Yes, but how safe is that?

Comment: Provides the same safety as entering your password on an HTTPS site

Comment: @Eric *"Every os is compromised by the government"* -- Which government, American? What's your source on that? I think I've heard rumors about the NSA trying to insert backdoor code in Linux wifi drivers, but they were found out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if a lib is open source you can check wether it's safe or not by looking at the source code. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/smtplib.py